# compare two xsl variables to find differences

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

i have two xsl variables :

```
<xsl:variable name="nutrientDetail">
  <value>nutrientTypeCode</value>
  <value>dailyValueIntakePercent</value>
  <value>measurementPrecision</value>
  <value>quantityContained</value>
</xsl:variable>



   <xsl:variable name="nutrientDetailArray">
      <v>nutrientTypeCode</v>
      <v>measurementPrecision</v>
      <v>quantityContained</v>
    </xsl:variable>
```

i want to find the uncommon one how do i do it?
i.e i have to extract dailyValueIntakePercent in case
and create an element of it .

Answer (score 0):

`<xsl:copy-of select="$nutrientDetail/value[not(. = $nutrientDetailArray/v)]"/>` copies the `value` elements from the first variable which have no equal `v` element from the second.